# Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("/First", null) in the _WidgetsAppState

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart, dart-pub

So, i'm trying to create an app in flutter and cannot work my way around the syntax code. The error is that Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("/First", null) in the _WidgetsAppState.[enter link description here](https://pastebin.com/S3AwREAT). Ps new to flutter.Below is the code to my link

```
[this link is for my code][1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your route name is `'/first'` so you should use `Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/first');`

You're using `'/First'` on your `signIn()` function so it looks like a simple capitalization error!